# XAML WPF DataGrid: reduce columns width to fit its content while scrolling except one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692672/wpf-datagrid-reduce-column-width-to-fit-its-content-while-scrolling) is the solution to automatically reduce DataGrid columns width during scrolling.
I need a slightly modified version where last column fills all row width left after other columns.

The old solution:

```
private void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not DataGrid dg) return;
    foreach (var c in dg.Columns) c.Width = 0;
    e.Row.UpdateLayout();
    foreach (var c in dg.Columns) c.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
}
```

If `dg.Columns.Last().Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);` added at the end of the method last column not respects other columns `Auto` size and forces its size to 20px (see the pic).
[image]

**UPDATE:**

The reason I've required described behaviour is for selecting row when mouse clicked on any place of the row. The row did not select when I clicked right side of the row - the was no cell. I've achieved this by adding `MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42156961/3230694).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `DataGrid` can't handle all the changes in one go, but you can "stagger" the update and let an "intermediate" layout be performed by putting the last part on the event loop, e.g., like this:

```
private void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not DataGrid dg) return;
    foreach (var c in dg.Columns) c.Width = 0;
    foreach (var c in dg.Columns.SkipLast(1)) c.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;            
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((DataGridColumn lc) => lc.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star), dg.Columns.Last());
}
```

This is very much not a pretty solution, and the grid flickers a bit due to the visible changes in column width. Maybe it can be improved, e.g., by detecting when it is actually necessary to "reset" the widths. You decide if it is good enough.

EDIT - Here is a slightly less flickering version by setting the last column to the same width during the intermediate layout:

```
private void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not DataGrid dg) return;
    foreach (var c in dg.Columns.SkipLast(1)) c.Width = 0;
    var lastColumn = dg.Columns.Last();
    lastColumn.Width = lastColumn.ActualWidth;
    foreach (var c in dg.Columns.SkipLast(1)) c.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;            
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((DataGridColumn lc) => 
        lc.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star), lastColumn);
}
```

EDIT 2 - A refactor to make it a bit clearer:

```
private void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not DataGrid dg) return;
    foreach (var c in dg.Columns.SkipLast(1))
    {
        c.Width = 0;
        c.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
    }
    var lastColumn = dg.Columns.Last();
    lastColumn.Width = lastColumn.ActualWidth;            
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(static (DataGridColumn lc) => 
        lc.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star), lastColumn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `UpdateLayout` call is totally redundant. Modifying the `Width` will automatically trigger a layout pass. Additionally, both iterations should be merged into a single iteration in order to improve the performance.
The complete implementation is very questionable in terms of user experience: in case the user adjusts the column's width, you would override and reset his customizations, which provides a poor experience. Also the grid would potentially resize itself constantly, which looks and feels odd too. You should at least set `DataGrid.CanUserResizeColumns` to `false`.
I believe that adding a column filter, that allows the user to hide particular columns in order to compact the view, has a higher value.

From the code you have posted, it's not possible to tell exactly what is going on or what could cause the issue. The actual layout configuration of your `DataGrid` control and its context is apparently undisclosed.

However, the issue could be related to how the `DataGrid` is calculating the width for each column, in case you give the `DataGrid` a fixed `Width` and this value would cause the content to exceed the available viewport width (the `ScrollViewer` would appear in this case):

a) In case of each column width is set to `Auto`, the `DataGrid` would simply give each column the required minimum width.

b) In case a column's width is set to star `*` size, the assigned width is calculated relative to the available remaining space.
In order to calculate a reasonable value, the algorithm would use the effective size of the `DataGrid`.
The point is, that when using a `ScrollViewer`, the virtual width would be infinite. Now, if the algorithm would set the last column's width to infinite, you would get a very tiny scroll bar. Therefore, infinite is not a reasonable value. In effect, the final width can not be calculated. That's why the algorithm falls back to use the effective width of the `DataGrid`, which is the `ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth`. The result is that all columns must be sqeezed into the available viewport space, causing columns to clip their headers and cell content.

I can provide two solutions.

The first solution is to use a fixed `Width` for the last column like `1000` DIPs.
This solution does scale very bad. The last column would have either a too small width or a too extreme width that does not make much sense (that's why a reasonable width for the last column can't be calculated - what is reasonable in this context?).

The second and better solution would try to detect if the `ScrollViewer` can scroll: in this case the last column would be at least partially out of view. This results in a reasonable `Width` for the last column of `Auto`: the minimal required space.
The other case, when the `ScrollViewer` can't scroll, is when all columns are visible in the viewport. This results in a reasonable `Width` of `*` in order to allow the last column to fill the remaining space:

```cs
private void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

  foreach (var dataGridColumn in dataGrid.Columns)
  {
    dataGridColumn.Width = 0;
    dataGridColumn.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
  }

  if (TryFindVisualChildElementByName(dataGrid, string.Empty, out ScrollViewer scrollViewer) 
    && scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth == 0)
  {
    dataGrid.Columns.Last().Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
  }
}

public static bool TryFindVisualChildElementByName<TChild>(
  DependencyObject parent,
  string childElementName,
  out TChild resultElement) where TChild : FrameworkElement
{
  resultElement = null;

  if (parent is Popup popup)
  {
    parent = popup.Child;
    if (parent == null)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

    if (childElement is TChild frameworkElement)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(childElementName) 
        || frameworkElement.Name.Equals(childElementName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        resultElement = frameworkElement;
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (TryFindVisualChildElementByName(childElement, childElementName, out resultElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: ty for detailed explanation. Unfortunately you soluion does not solve the problem, result is the same in my case.

Comment: It does exactly what you require. Maybe you can test it in a blank project and then find out why it doesn't work in your application. As I said before, you should provide more context.

Comment: The solution works on empty project. However I prefer @Magnus's less code solution. Ty for your attention.

Comment: The problem with the accepted solution is that deferring the execution using the Dispatcher is a nondeterministic behaviour. This solution should be the last resort. The TryFindVisualChildElementByName method should be an extension method in your private library. So line count should not be the argument here. Anyway, I'm glad I could contribute.

Comment: Yes, the suggested solution is a generic pattern for control/wpf updates that are difficult or impossible to do in a single step, but it has to be used with caution regarding concurrency and idempotency. In this case, the execution of a new LoadingRow-event might be interleaved with the previous event's dispatched execution, but the last update will always be with the state you want (unless you add/remove columns while the user scrolls, but the next LoadingRow event fixes that) .